# All boolean combinations from 2 numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

Is there an existing function in numpy that takes 2 numpy arrays (x,y) and returns a boolean matrix for each i,j (x[i]>y[j])

For example, let x = [3, 4 ,5] and y = [1, 2, 3] and I want

```
res = [ [True, True, False],

        [True, True, True],

        [True, True, True] ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a function here, just array broadcasting can work if you shape your arrays properly. I think you want this approach, which makes `x` a column vector and `y` a row vector:

```
x = np.array([3,4,5])
y = np.array([1,2,3])

res = x[:,None] > y[None,:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy, you can cast your x and y list to arrays like so:`x = np.array([3,4,5]) y=np.array([1,2,3])` and then numpy does elementwise comparisons by simply doing: `print(x > y)`